# Creating multiple enclosing shortcodes and fixing JS issues on click

Tags: jquery, shortcode, javascript, front-end

I have the following shortcode to create multiple 'more' sections in any page/post:

```
function more_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ){
    return '<div id="more-outer"><a href="#" id="more-link">More</a><div id="more-inner">'. $content .'</div></div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'more', 'more_shortcode' );
```

I am about to write jQuery function for showing/hiding the `#more-inner` when `#more-outer` is clicked, but the problem is that the shortcode can be used multiple times in the same page, so it would basically generate many divs with same ids and once any of the would be clicked, all of the `#div-inner` elements would be shown.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:-

```
function more_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ){
    return '<div id="more-outer-'.$atts['id'].'"><a href="#" id="more-link-'.$atts['id'].'">More</a><div id="more-inner">'. $content .'</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'more', 'more_shortcode' );
```

Usage:-

```
[more id='1']This is one.[/more]

[more id='2']This is two.[/more]

[more id='3']This is three.[/more]
```

Output:-

```
<div id="more-outer-1"><a href="#" id="more-link-1">More</a><div id="more-inner">This is one.</div></div>
<div id="more-outer-2"><a href="#" id="more-link-2">More</a><div id="more-inner">This is two.</div></div>
<div id="more-outer-3"><a href="#" id="more-link-3">More</a><div id="more-inner">This is three.</div></div>
```

JS Script:-

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(document).on('click', '#more-outer-1', function(e){
                /* Do action for click on div with id more-outer-1 */
            });
        $(document).on('click', '#more-outer-2', function(e){
                /* Do action for click on div with id more-outer-2 */
            });
        $(document).on('click', '#more-outer-3', function(e){
                /* Do action for click on div with id more-outer-3 */
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Havent tried it yet, but looks like a very elegant solution. Thanks a lot!